# How to properly use PDO prepare execute statement when inserting a large array

Tags: mysql, arrays, insert, pdo, prepare

I have a foreach loop setup so that I can insert a huge array (about 200 keys). I admit that I do not fully understand how PDO works but I'm an idiot and reading tons of literature has only made me angry and more confused. In all of the examples I saw, the array was spelled out in the prepare statement. I cannot do that because I've "built" the array through 200 iterations of the foreach loop.

So how do I do an insert into without explicitly restating the array in the prepare statement? Thank you for helping me not kill myself with a spork.

```
        $ar_header = array();
        $ar_data = array();
        for ($rowcount=1; $rowcount<=$tblrows; $rowcount++)
 {
        for ($cellcount=1; $cellcount<=$tblcells; $cellcount++)
        {
        if (isset($_POST["row"."$rowcount"."cell"."$cellcount"])){ 


        // use this format as it matches with the database          
        $header = ($array1[$rowcount]).($array2[$cellcount]); 
        $data = $_POST ["row"."$rowcount"."cell"."$cellcount"];
        //the array will add each new header and data repectively
        $ar_header[] = $header;
        $ar_data[] = $data;
        $ar_god = array_combine($ar_header, $ar_data);



        }
        }
   }
  $qry = ("INSERT INTO invforms ('header') VALUES ('value')");
        $prep = $conn->prepare($qry);


       $prep->execute($ar_god);
```

Comment: Please read [PDO Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) and see where your code is wrong. Then you can EDIT your question if you still have problems